# Attempt to insert nil object from objects[1] when upload image to firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, firebase-storage

I'm getting this error when i try to upload an image to firebase storage. I tried to re-write the current view and change some things but again when i click the upload button the app crash and i'm getting the same error on the log. All I know is that the error is in the function I call when the user uploads the photo to firebase storage.

Note: I'm beginner on IOS development :-)

Thanks.

**The error:**

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

**My code:**

```
struct SelectProfileImageView: View {
    
    @State var showActionSheet = false
    @State var showImagePicker = false
    
    @State var sourceType:UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
    
    @State var upload_image:UIImage?
    
    @State var download_image:UIImage?
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack{
            //Uploading image
                if upload_image != nil {
                Image(uiImage: upload_image!)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width:120, height:120)
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "timelapse")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width:300, height:300)
            }
                Spacer()
                if download_image != nil {
                    Image(uiImage: download_image!)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width:120, height:120)
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "timelapse")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width:120, height:120)
                }
            }.padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                self.showActionSheet = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Select Image")
            }).actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet){
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Add a picture to your post"), message: nil, buttons: [
                    //Button1
                    
                    .default(Text("Camera"), action: {
                        self.showImagePicker = true
                        self.sourceType = .camera
                    }),
                    //Button2
                    .default(Text("Photo Library"), action: {
                        self.showImagePicker = true
                        self.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                    }),
                    
                    //Button3
                    .cancel()
                    
                ])
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker){
                imagePicker(image: self.$upload_image, showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, sourceType: self.sourceType)
                
            }
            
            
            Button(action: {
                if let thisImage = self.upload_image {
                    uploadImage(image: thisImage)
                } else {
                    print("")
                }
                
            }){
                Text("Upload Image")
            }
            
            
        }
    }
}

func uploadImage(image:UIImage){
    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1){
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        storage.reference().putData(imageData, metadata: nil) {
            (_, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("an error has occurred - \(err.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("image uploaded successfully")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("coldn't unwrap/case image to data")
    }
}


struct SelectProfileImageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SelectProfileImageView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be related to the Firebase configurations

Comment: Got the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: I don't remember exactly how, but I think that you need to make sure that the image is not nil (null), you can make a loading screen or something like that until the image is loaded

Comment: @GSepetadelis thx but the image is not null :( I've created an issue on the official repo https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what the problem was on my side.

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
storage.reference().putData(imageData, metadata: nil) {
```

I did something similar to the above.
Make sure to use the reference from the child. You can't write things in the root folder.

so

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
storage.reference().child("some/path").putData(imageData, metadata: nil) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My firebase upload was failing, but the error wasn't showing. It would crash with that error instead. React native has a hard time with async hooks it was sucking up the error instead of displaying it, not just in useEffect, but in regular hooks. On web you can run an async function in a hook, but apparently not with react native.  Once I turned the async function into a .then function I was able to see the error. It was a rules violation.